# I have some questions when compilered android source

Tags: android, linux

1.In my project,I need to compiler the android source Which version is 5.1, and my operating system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

2.In the system terminal, when I executed the command "mm -j4", some problems  happened.

3.Important Logs in the terminal:

```
     ============================================
    PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
    PLATFORM_VERSION=5.1
    TARGET_PRODUCT=full
    TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
    TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
    TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
    TARGET_ARCH=arm
    TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
    TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
    TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
    HOST_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_OS=linux
    HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.2.0-27-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
    HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
    BUILD_ID=LMY47D
    OUT_DIR=out
    ============================================

    Checking build tools versions...
    including ./abi/cpp/Android.mk ...
    including ./art/Android.mk ...
    including ./bionic/Android.mk ...
    including ./bootable/bootloader/lk/Android.mk ...
    including ./bootable/bootloader/preloader/Android.mk ...
    including ./bootable/recovery/Android.mk ...
    including ./build/libs/host/Android.mk ...
    including ./build/target/board/Android.mk ...
    including ./build/target/product/security/Android.mk ...
    including ./build/tools/Android.mk ...
    including ./cts/Android.mk ...
    including ./dalvik/Android.mk ...
    including ./development/apps/BluetoothDebug/Android.mk ...
    including ./development/apps/BuildWidget/Android.mk ...
    including ./development/apps/CustomLocale/Android.mk ...
    including ./development/apps/Development/Android.mk ...
    including ./development/apps/DevelopmentSettings/Android.mk ...

    ·····(too many logs,omit some lines)

    including ./vendor/dolby/Ds1UI/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/dolby/ds/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/google/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/helytech/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/lentek/libs/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/mediatek/Android.mk ...
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libm/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libm_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstdc++_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: external/zlib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libz_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: system/core/libcutils/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcutils_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: external/compiler-rt/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcompiler_rt-extras_intermediates/export_includes
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libexpat/expat.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libexpat/expat_external.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libexpat/expat.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libexpat/expat_external.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/png.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/pngconf.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/pngusr.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/png.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/pngconf.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/pngusr.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/selinux/selinux.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/selinux/label.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/selinux/context.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/selinux/avc.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/selinux/android.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/selinux/selinux.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/selinux/label.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/selinux/context.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/selinux/avc.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/selinux/android.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas_types.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas_reverb.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/jet.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/ARM_synth_constants_gnu.inc
Export includes file: bionic/libdl/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdl_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_common_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdl_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcompiler_rt-extras_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: build/libs/host/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: build/tools/acp/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_aeabi_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_bionic_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_cxa_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_dns_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_freebsd_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_gdtoa_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_malloc_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_netbsd_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_openbsd_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_stack_protector_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_syscalls_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_tzcode_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: external/jemalloc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libjemalloc_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_aeabi_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_bionic_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_cxa_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_dns_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_freebsd_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_gdtoa_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_malloc_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_netbsd_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_openbsd_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_stack_protector_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_syscalls_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_tzcode_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libjemalloc_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libm_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: bionic/libm/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libm_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstdc++_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libz_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: system/core/liblog/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblog_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: external/zlib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/gzip_static_intermediates/export_includes
Notice file: external/zlib/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/bin/gzip_static.txt
Notice file: external/zlib/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libz.a.txt
Notice file: bionic/libc/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libc.a.txt
Notice file: system/core/libcutils/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libcutils.a.txt
Notice file: bionic/libc/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libc.so.txt
Notice file: bionic/libc/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libc_common.a.txt
Notice file: bionic/libdl/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libdl.so.txt
Notice file: bionic/libm/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libm.so.txt
Notice file: bionic/libm/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libm.a.txt
Notice file: bionic/libc/NOTICE -- out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libstdc++.so.txt
Export includes file: frameworks/native/libs/input/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: system/core/libutils/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: system/core/libcutils/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcutils_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: system/core/liblog/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblog_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/import_includes
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libxlog_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblog_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

4.what I can do to finish compilered android source? Help me please, if you have solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
Execute the command "lunch" and choose the version which want to compile.
Then just make it.